# How to detect what class an object in an array is in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, oop, class, iteration

I'm working on a highly object oriented project in JavaScript. I have an array[] of objects of different classes and I'm iterating through it and I want to check the class of the object at array[i]. Is there any way for me to detect this? This might help you understand what I mean:

```
var pieces = [new Pawn(), new Rook(), new Knight()];
for(var i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++){
    if(pieces[i] == Rook){
        //Do something with the rook
    }
}
```

This is the general idea of what I need to do, but the if condition is the tricky bit. How can I detect the class of the element at pieces[i]? My fallback solution is to give every object a "type" field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can depend on how you have inheritance set up, but in general you check that with the [`instanceof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```
if(pieces[i] instanceof Rook) // ...
```

Comment: Be careful with *instanceof*, all it does is check that `Rook.prototype` is on the private `[[prototype]]` chain of `pieces[i]`. That may be OK depending on how you have implemented your inheritance and what you actually need to know. The constructor property might be more suitable (it's a public property so can be set to a suitable value when setting up inheritance initially).